# Emulate visitors real time web app

Tags: javascript, android, performance, websocket, performance-testing

I am developping a real-time web app where users can see others move on the map.
I'm using websockets for this and did some test, but on a realy smale scale.

So basicly, everytime a user his position updates on the map, his coordinates are send to the server and sends them to all the clients. If there will be many users, there will be a lot of data going on.

I was wondering if I could emulate visitors, so I can see how the app reacts, before this is going live.

Comment: If you got this far, I dare say the answer is "yes". Build a standalone application that sends information (from a fixed position plus some random offset), then set N copies of this app running.

Comment: Alright, that triggerd something in my head. I'll give it a try!